# Why data from server doesn't display in AngularJS application?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple AngularJS application, i have the page with albums at the **Albums.html** page, after click to album i redirect to **AlbumPhotos.html** and send $http.post request to server and get all photos of album from server:

```
//Empty Photo Array
$scope.AllPhotosOfAlbumArray = [];
// Get All Photos Of Album
$scope.getAlbumPhotos = function (albumId) {
    console.log(albumId);
    logicOfMyApp.getAllPhotosOfALmubFromSrverFunc(albumId).then(function (photos) {
        $scope.AllPhotosOfAlbumArray = photos;
        console.log($scope.AllPhotosOfAlbumArray);
    });
};
```

**getAllPhotosOfALmubFromSrverFunc()** method code:

```
getAllPhotosOfALmubFromSrverFunc: function(albumId)
    {
        var photosPromise = $q.defer();
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/api/getPhotos',
            data: albumId
        };
        $http(req).success(function(res) {
           return photosPromise.resolve(res)
        }).error(function(error){
            return photosPromise.reject(error);
        });
        
        return photosPromise.promise;
     }
```

I get data from server:
[image]

But when i trying display data from **$scope.AllPhotosOfAlbumArray** use **ng-repeat** directive at the page:

```
<!--Display all Photos Of Album-->
<div ng-repeat="photo in AllPhotosOfAlbumArray">
    {{photo}}
</div>
```

it display nothing.

Maybe somebody knows how i can resolve it ?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: @CeylanB. No  I haven't errors.

Comment: Try add some value to photo array and check if they will show

Comment: @Geding I added static data like this [1,2,3,4] and it displays.

Comment: Can you check if that ng-repeat is working with data from server adding inside some text (and check if it display)?

Comment: @Geding I don't know maybe is important I add to top of my jsController Console.log message, and after load the page I have two messages [screenshot](http://prnt.sc/c8f3r9).

Comment: @Geding I added to array text ["f","s","th"] and it displays(

Comment: @VladimirKhodakovskey I dont see any issues with the code, can you create a plunker

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes I can Crete plunker, but I don' know how I can emulate request to server use plunker, ok, I'll do it. Thank you!

Comment: Everything looks good; only thing I noticed is "return photoPromise.resolve()". Do you really need to "return" it? IMO you already returned your promise, and in success you could just resolve it with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something i noticed in your code is `return photosPromise.resolve(res)` and `return photosPromise.reject(error);`  you don't need to use `return` on those lines because that is not the way to use `$q` in angularjs. here is a snippet from [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) documentation.

```
function asyncGreet(name) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  setTimeout(function() {
    deferred.notify('About to greet ' + name + '.');

    if (okToGreet(name)) {
      deferred.resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
    } else {
      deferred.reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
    }
  }, 1000);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: I change my method like you, it return photos, but it still doesn't display, I use another way to resolve it, I using a data-ng-init directive, and get data after load the page.